# List of vectors (C++)

Tags: c++, stl

I want to create a list of 4 vectors with variables sizes (n1 n2 3 and n4) and all filled with 0's
How can i do that ? I can do a `list<vector<float> > mylist` But how to put the size of mylist[0] to n1, etc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// on a C++11 enabled compiler
std::list<std::vector<float>> listofvectors = {
    std::vector<float>(n1, 0.f)
  , std::vector<float>(n2, 0.f)
  , std::vector<float>(n3, 0.f)
  , std::vector<float>(n4, 0.f)
};
// or more traditional
std::list< std::vector<float> > listofvectors;
listofvectors.push_back(std::vector<float>(n1, 0.f));
// so forth
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being a total newbie, but why do you write 0.f instead of 0 ? Something related to float ? Can't we just write 0 ?

Comment: @sftrabbit No, why? Boost always uses that, it's much better when specifying initializer lists, since first character is `:` and next are commas, and thus it's easier to format these lines. We are yet to see the "standard" way in multiline initializer lists, I guess.

Comment: @user2370139 It creates a float literal instead of int one (plain 0). It don't have much importance here, but otherwise it's a good habit to clearly state the type of the number. Consider `auto f = 0.f;`

Comment: @sftrabbit I took it over from haskell. The real benefit is to me, that it is much easier to work with when editing code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add these vectors to your list:

```
mylist.push_back(vector<float>(n1, 0.f));
mylist.push_back(vector<float>(n2, 0.f));
mylist.push_back(vector<float>(n3, 0.f));
mylist.push_back(vector<float>(n4, 0.f));
```

`vector` constructor taking two parameters will create one with (first parameter) elements all set to the value of the second parameter.